# Conventional angularjs syntax to es6 syntax in order to migrate

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ecmascript-6

How can I set a static property to a **class** in es6?

Here is my problem:
I had a factory called **Commands**.

#### commandsFactory.js

```
angular.module('mainModule')
.factory('Commands', [function () {
return{
// a lot of commands here
}
```

That factory was used as a dependency in another factory called **Module**:

#### moduleFactory.js

```
.factory('K_Module', ['Commands', function (Commands) {
// here I'm using Commands anytime and anywhere I need
// also all the instance created by this factory had access to Commands

}
```

After refactoring I have the following:

#### commandFactory.js

```
function CommandsFactory() {
return all my commands
}
export {
    CommandsFactory
}
```

I added a new file in order to export a module called

#### data.module.js

```
import $parser from '../parsers/parsers.module';
import $communication from '../communication/communication.module';
import {Connectors, CommandsFactory} from './Commands'

export default require('angular')
    .module('core.data', [$parser, $communication])
    .factory("Connectors", Connectors)
    .factory("Commands", CommandsFactory)
    .name;
```

I'm calling that module in another module called

#### kModule

```
import $data from '../core/data/data.module';
import {K_Module, K_Matrix} from './ModuleFactory'
export default require('angular')
    .module('kModules', [$data])
    .service('K_Module', K_Module)
    .name;
```

The new K_Module looks like this (and here are the question):

```
class K_Module {
    constructor(data, Commands, DataProxy, $q) {// I don't want to include these dependencies (except data) each time I create a K_Module
        'ngInject';
        let _self = this;
        _self.Commands = Commands;
        _self.DataProxy = DataProxy;
        _self.$q = $q;
//... other stuff
```

Is it possible to make Commands, $q and DataProxy as static properties?
So I can have inheritance to theses properties and don't have to write each time?
var

Comment: Of course you can make it global. You can make anything global. Of course, that also completely goes against the module system, which was put in place to not pollute the global namespace. Injecting them into the constructor makes it so that you can change, say, what Promise library you want to use. So you can use bluebird instead of Q, for instance. This is especially nice when testing, so that you aren't dependent on 30 files just to test a single function.

Comment: So, in your opinion it's a best practice to inject it in the constructor? Isn't redundantly if the same object is used in a lot of other objects?

Comment: AngularJS invokes classes with `new ClassName`. The only place to inject dependencies in a class is in the constructor. That's the way AngularJS dependency injection works.

Comment: @georgeawg so I am right with my refactoring?(thx for editing my question)

Comment: The decision to re-factor to use classes is a matter of opinion. On one hand the code involves more effort; on the other, class types are regular structures that can be analyzed and refactored automatically. They are definitely the way to go if you intend to migrate to frameworks that use Ahead-of-Time compilation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My probleme was the redundancy of each of my dependencies.

Well, the solution was simply to make them as global variables for the current module.

```
let _Commands;
let _DataProxy;
let _$q;
class K_Module {
        constructor(data, Commands, DataProxy, $q) {// I don't want to include these dependencies (except data) each time I create a K_Module
            'ngInject';
            let _self = this;
            _Commands = Commands;
            _DataProxy = DataProxy;
            _$q = $q;
    //... other stuff
```

That way each of the instances in that module will have access to that variables